# MS Access: Lookup excluding already-selected values; check unique key before record entry complete

Tags: ms-access, vba, duplicates

I'm currently struggling how to set up validation rules for forms in either Datasheet or Form view that trigger immediately upon going to either another field within the record or to another record entirely.

My form is designed to add records to one destination table where the primary key column needs to match a value of a specific field in any record of a source table. The rest of the fields in the form (and destination table) are for general user input (some DateTime fields, some text, some decimal).

I can get Access to display a standard error dialogue when a user attempts to free-enter a value not on the list immediately after selection of another field or record. The error displayed is

> **The text you entered isn't an item in the list.**
>   Select an item from the list, or enter text that matches one of the listed items"

And if I reselect a lookup value already selected and go to the next record, I get

> The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship. Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again.

**However, I'd like that error (or similar) to appear immediately if going to another field within the same record.**  In other words, I want it to tell me that it's a duplicate before allowing the user to fill out the rest of the current record in the form or table.

I would like the selection list be restricted to values not previously present in the destination table. Obviously if editing an already-created entry, you should be able to keep the value you had previously (i.e. that value wouldn't be excluded from the dropdown list).

Alternatively there would be a selection dialogue that would appear if an otherwise valid value was duplicated.

> **Duplicate Value**
>   You've already used that value. Would you like to change this record or the previously-entered record.
>   ⪡ This One ⪢ < Previous >

If "Previous" is selected, it would jump up to the same field in the indicated record, providing a dropdown list for re-selection (and once done would jump back to the "current" record and autoselect the temporarily duplicated value.

I'll edit this post in a bit with my table design details, as well as source setups for the form.

Answer (score 0):

"Solved" this in VBA.

```vb
Private Sub MyControl_AfterUpdate()
    newval = Me.MyControl.Value
    oldval = Me.MyControl.OldValue
    If newval = oldval Then Exit Sub ' everything's okay
    Dim rs As Object
    Set rs = Me.Form.Recordset
    whereclause = "MyControl = '" & newval & "'"
    qry = "SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM MyQuery WHERE " & whereclause
    qrs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(qry)
    If qrs.Count = 1 Then cnt = qrs(0).Value
    If cnt >= 1 Then
        selval = MsgBox("Would you like to keep your selection for this record?" & vbCrLf & "[yes = change previous record's MyField; no = change MyField for this record]", vbYesNo Or VbMsgBoxStyle.vbExclamation Or vbSystemModal Or vbDefaultButton2 Or vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Duplicate MyField selection encountered")
        If selval = vbYes Then
            ' set focus to the other entry, preserving selection here
            thissel = Me.MyControl.ListIndex
            Me.MyControl.Value = "temp" ' if a string is okay & so we can jump away from this record
            thisloc = Me.Form.CurrentRecord ' record number
            rs.Findfirst (whereclause)
            thatloc = Me.Form.CurrentRecord
            Debug.Print (thisloc & "now  ;  was" & thatloc)
            Me.MyControl.Value = "invalid"
            DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acGoTo, thisloc  ' jump to the new row
            Me.MyControl.Value = newval
            DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acGoTo, thatloc  ' jump to the one to change
            If thissel <= 0 Then thissel = 1 ' may not be useful, given the error handling below
            On Error Resume Next
            Me.MyControl.ListIndex = thissel - 1
            On Error GoTo 0
            Me.MyControl.Dropdown
        ElseIf selval = vbNo Then
            Me.MyControl.Value = Me.MyControl.OldValue
            Me.MyControl.Undo ' for some reason this doesn't clear the "dirty" bit, resulting in the edit pencil showing up for the row.
            Me.MyControl.SetFocus
        End If
    Else
        Debug.Print ("There were no matches! Das ist gut")
    End If
End Sub
```

**Residual Issue(s)**

1. Selecting "Yes" from the dialogue and then hitting escape puts the invalid "invalid" string into the box, which ignores any requirement to restrict the final selection to one in the list (ie *Limit to List = 1*). Ideally this would "roll back" the two rows.
2. Maybe I should change this to an OnExit Event so it doesn't trigger before I even leave the cell? Not sure if the primary key violation would happen before this triggers though. OnChange triggers much too frequently (every time you down-arrow through the list).